# Class inheritance design with protected methods and run time base handlers

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance

Using C#, I got a class called BaseConfigurations which handles CRUD operations. This class also contains a protected method which is used inside the CRUD handling methods:

```
public class BaseConfigurations : ICRUDHandler
{
    public virtual bool CreateSetting(string someData)
    {
        //some logic
        ProtectedMethod();
        //more logic
    }
    
    protected virtual void ProtectedMethod() { ... }
}
```

Now there's a different version which can handle the CRUD operation a bit different:

```
public class BaseConfigurationsV2 : BaseConfigurations { ... }
```

There are 2 instances of `BaseConfigurations` and `BaseConfigurationsV2` living at the same time and should be invoked based on some logic I have.

Now there's another class which handles specifically secret data:

```
public class SecretConfigurations : BaseConfigurations
{
   public ICRUDHandler _crudHandler;
   public SecretConfigurations(ICRUDHandler handler) 
   { 
      _crudHandler = handler; //this handler gets either the instance of `BaseConfigurations` or `BaseConfigurationsV2` 
   }

   public override bool CreateSetting(string data)
   {
      _crudHandler.CreateSetting(data);
      //adds additional logic
   }

   public override void ProtectedMethod() { ... }
}
```

My problem here is that because the ICRUDHandler which SecretConfigurations receives is either BaseConfigurations or BaseConfigurationsV2, it doesn't know the protected method which was overriden in SecretConfigurations and doesn't invoke it.

The easy way to fix it is to probably just make another class of `SecretConfigurationsV2` which will derive from BaseConfigurationsV2 and then have the handler be initialized to either `SecretConfigurations` or `SecretConfigurationsV2`, but that involves code duplication.

How would you design a fix for this issue?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How does "ICRUDHandler" look like? What is the reason for deriving BaseConfigurationsV2  from BaseConfigurations? What is the reason for deriving SecretConfigurations  from BaseConfigurations? The whole purpose of why you are using inheritance here is a mystery to me.

Comment: research "template method". That plus an abstract class works well in an inheritance situation where a base class method contains common behavior and other code in that method is overridden by subclasses.

Comment: ICRUDHandler is an interface with general signatures of CRUD operations - like the CreateSetting example, it also have read, update, delete. About BaseConfigurationsV2 - the service itself has 2 versions and each should handle the CRUD operations in a slightly different way in a way such that BaseConfigurationsV2 adds some more logic to the logic in BaseConfigurations. About SecretConfigurations, it was there before BaseConfigurationsV2 and then it derived from BaseConfiugrations so I tried not changing alot, but I can change it if needed.

Comment: @radarbob a template method does not solve the problem. SecretConfigurations should handle the settings either as a BaseConfigurations or as a BaseConfigurationsV2. Both options are of 2 different versions of the same service which lives at the same time

Comment: Comments are not a good place to clarify questions. Use the "edit" button for adding expressive examples to your question, then we can see what we can do for your.

Comment: The most unclear point I see is the role of "ProtectedMethod". What purpose does it have,  why is there another overriden version of it in SecretConfigurations, and in which way does it differ from the version in BaseConfiguration.?

Comment: I don't understand this: "because the ICRUDHandler which SecretConfigurations receives is either BaseConfigurations or BaseConfigurationsV2, it doesn't know the protected method which was overriden in SecretConfigurations and doesn't invoke it."  It's protected, so nothing outside can see it, so in order for it to be useful, *something* in the base class should be calling it so that it will call down to the derived class version.

Comment: @Craig Imagine a method called in the base class but its overridden in a derived class. An instance of a dynamic type of the derived class would have called the overridden method

Answer (score 2):

If you run into a problem with inheritance, switch to composition instead.

Its hard to say more without knowing what the methods and classes do.

```
public class Configurations : ICRUDHandler
{
    public Configurations(IProtectedMethod protMethod)
    public virtual bool CreateSetting(string someData)
    {
        //some logic
        protMethod.ProtectedMethod(this.whateverData);
        //more logic
    }
}
   

public class ProtV1 : IProtectedMethod 
{
...
}
public class ProtV2 : IProtectedMethod 
{
...
}
public class ProtSecret : IProtectedMethod 
{
...
}

etc
```

Comment: What about all the other classes I mentioned? Other types of configurations handling

Comment: you only mention the three and the only method that changes is protectedMethod. So I dont have much to go on.

Comment: But each class has entirely different logic for each virtual method. Here you only describe using composition for the implementation of the protected method, but not how to get the correct logic of the other methods

Comment: The same pattern would apply, refactor the logic into injected sub classes. difficult to say without examples

Comment: I am sure you are right that the OP can solve their problems by favoring composition over inheritance. Where I am not so sure is whether "ProtectedMethod" needs to become subject of the strategy pattern, as shown in your answer, or "CreateSetting".

Comment: yup, they are all ICrudHandlers after all.

Comment: @DocBrown I might have misunderstood what you meant, but it seems that the protected method must become a part of everything since the protected method is being overriden only in the class I showed SecretConfigurations  which is at the lowest part of the inheritance tree. The behavior is that BaseConfiguration will call its public methods, but inside will invoke a protected method so when in the context of CreateSetting in BaseConfiguration, the protected method of SecretConfiguration should be called

Comment: he's saying you could just make all my IProtectedMethod derived classes controllers and inject them into whatever uses them. as you don't have any shared code between them in your example.

Comment: @Ewan: no, I am saying I don't understand the question, the important details are missing.

Comment: I edited the question with a more detailed explanation. Hopefully it clears up the mess

Comment: can you put in some actual code in your example which wont work with the above solution and give stuff proper names?

Comment: @Ewan Its the same code as the original question, only without the handler in SecretConfigurations and without the class BaseConfigurationsV2

Answer (score 1):

So there's a lot of questions/concerns with your design, which the comments have already adequately addressed. I would suggest going back to the drawing board with this rather than trying to make your current design work.

But I do want to answer your specific question as a point of learning.

> My problem here is that because the ICRUDHandler which SecretConfigurations receives is either BaseConfigurations or BaseConfigurationsV2, it doesn't know the protected method which was overriden in SecretConfigurations.

This is not a problem, it is the language working by design. When you design a contract to do something, e.g.:

```
public interface IStringGenerator
{
    string Generate();
}
```

and then you write code that accepts a parameter of this interface type:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IStringGenerator generator;

    public MyService(IStringGenerator generator)
    {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public void DoAThing()
    {
        string result = this.generator.Generate();

        // do something with result
    }
}
```

Then you are **by design** stating that you accept *any* implementation of `IStringGenerator`. The logical conclusion there being that you intentionally don't want to have to be actively aware of the specific implementations of `IStringGenerator` that could possibly be passed into your `MyService`.

If you needed to know for a fact that `MyService` only wishes to accept `MyFancyGenerator : IStringGenerator` and not `MyBasicGenerator : IStringGenerator`, then you should explicitly ask for that type:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyFancyGenerator fancyGenerator;

    public MyService(MyFancyGenerator fancyGenerator)
    {
        this.fancyGenerator = fancyGenerator;
    }

    public void DoAThing()
    {
        string result = this.fancyGenerator.Generate();

        // do something with result
    }
}
```

The short answer here is "don't downcast into a base type when you care about the specific derived type". Doing so means you are writing code that does not match how you expect it to behave, which is going to always be a source of problems and confusion.

Comment: I edited the question with a more detailed explanation. Hopefully it clears up the mess

Comment: @CodeMonkey None of the information you added invalidates the core of any of the posted answers. It's not that we don't understand your idea, it's that we're suggesting you to approach this differently from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is still somewhat unclear to me, after thinking a while about it, I guess what you want is to exchange the the `ProtectedMethod` called inside `BaseConfigurations.CreateSetting`  when called in the context of `SecretConfigurations.CreateSetting`. For this purpose, I would use a run time mechanics to decide between the calls, not a compile time mechanics.

This can be achieved by making `ProtectedMethod` a run time parameter of CreateSetting, something along the line of this:

```
public class BaseConfigurations : ICRUDHandler
{
    public virtual bool CreateSetting(string someData)
    {
         CreateSetting(someData,ProtectedMethod1);
    }

    // no need to make this virtual here
    public bool CreateSetting(string someData, Action protectedMethod)
    {
        //some logic
        protectedMethod();
        //more logic
    }
    
    protected void ProtectedMethod1() { ... }
}
```

And in SecretConfigurations:

```
public class SecretConfigurations : ICRUDHandler   
{
   // not you wrote _crudHandler is always of type BaseConfigurations
   // or a subtype of it!
   public BaseConfigurations _crudHandler;

   // ...
   public override bool CreateSetting(string data)
   {
      _crudHandler.CreateSetting(data,ProtectedMethod2);
      //...
   }

   protected void ProtectedMethod2() { ... }
}
```

I renamed your `ProtectedMethod` to `ProtectedMethod1` and `ProtectedMethod2` to make the distinction more clearer. If your `ProtectedMethod` has parameters or return types, you may have to replace  `Action` by `Action<T1,T2,...>`, or `Func<T1, T2, ...>`. And if it becomes more complicated, you may introduce an interface `IProtectedMethod` for it and pass functor objects instead of simple delegates. But I guess you get idea.

Note this is somewhat similar to what [Ewan's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/450946) says, with the difference that the specific CRUD handler can be constructed first, and the decision which protected method is called is made later, depending on the context.

Comment: I edited the question with a more detailed explanation. Hopefully it clears up the mess

Comment: Did you see the edit?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: yes, but did you read my answer? Nothing in your extra explanation tells me my answer cannot be applied to it.

Comment: Yeah I initially thought of maybe adding another handler member just for the action but passing it as a parameter is cleaner. Even though it does seem that the answer can be applied, I believe you did it based on my initial thoughts of how to solve the issue I display in my edit. But let's say you only saw the edit itself as the question without the first part, you might have a better idea of how to design the system to answer that need displayed there?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: I still think your code examples are too contrived, and nothing in your extra explanation has changed this So it is up to *you* to transfer the suggestions I made to your *real* code, the parts of which I could only make blind guesses how it looks like .  The gist of my answer is, when you want to change certain behaviour in a context-dependend manner, consider to use a more functional approach and make the actions which are different functional parameters.

Comment: The code in the example is a shorten pseudo code but its exactly how the real one looks. Can you just look at the edit as a totally new question instead of thinking of it as clarification?